# Interceptor code not getting called when using http.post

Tags: angular5

I have written (copied from SO!) the following interceptor code. I want to modify the outgoing request and also intercept the response. However, I have noticed that the response never gets intercepted. Why? Is it because I am using `Rxjs`?

Interceptor code

```js
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log("outgoing request",request);
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    console.log("new outgoing request",request);

    return next
      .handle(request)
      .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('processing response', ev);  //I DON'T SEE THIS PRINT
        }
      });
  }
}
```

I am sending the request to the server as follows

```js
 return this.http.post(/*this.API_URL+*/this.SIGNIN_USER_URL,body,httpOptions)
      .map(response=>{
        console.log('response from backend service',response); //I SEE THIS PRINT
        let result= <ServerResponse>response; 
        console.log("result is "+result.result+' with additional information '+result.additionalInformation)
        return result;
      })
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Why is the interceptor code not getting hit?

Update - the provider code snippet in `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [WebToBackendInterfaceService, //some other provider
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor , //interceptor provider
      multi: true
    }],
```

I added a print between `do` and `if` (`console.log("got an event",ev)`. I can see the following message on console `got an event

```
{…}
​body: Object { result: "success", "additional-info": "found user" }
​headers: {…}
​lazyInit: function lazyInit()
​​lazyUpdate: null
​​normalizedNames: Map
​​​size: 0
​​​<entries>
​​​__proto__: Object { … }
​​__proto__: Object { has: has(), get: get(), keys: keys(), … }
​ok: true
​status: 200
​statusText: "OK"
​type: 4
​url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signin"
​__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpResponse(), clone: clone() }`
```

I dont know why the if statement isn't getting executed as it seems the event is of type `HttpResponse` (referring to  `​__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpResponse(), clone: clone() }`)

Comment: Can you show the code you used to provide it? (setting it up with Angular's dependency injection)

Comment: updated the questions

Comment: @Daniel - any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see if you log the `HttpEvent`s in your `.do((ev: HttpEvent<any>)`? Are your outgoing request logs from your `intercept` method being seen in the console?

Comment: Outgoing request is printed `outgoing request 
Object { url: "/ws/users/signin", body: "{\"signin-info\":{\"email\":\"d@d.com\",\"password\":\"d3\"}}", reportProgress: false, withCredentials: true, responseType: "json", method: "POST", headers: {…}, params: {…}, urlWithParams: "/ws/users/signin" }
main.bundle.js:420:9
new outgoing request 
Object { url: "/ws/users/signin", body: "{\"signin-info\":{\"email\":\"d@d.com\",\"password\":\"d3\"}}", reportProgress: false, withCredentials: true, responseType: "json", method: "POST", headers: {…}, params: {…}, urlWithParams: "/ws/users/signin" }`

Comment: updated the question again. Added a debug print

Comment: in the print, the type is 4 (`type: 4`). From documentation, `HttpEvent`'s values could be `type HttpEvent<T> = HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<T> | HttpProgressEvent | HttpUserEvent<T>`. So does 4 map to  `HttpProgressEvent` or `HttpUserEvent`

Comment: I put together a stackblitz using your code above and it works with a sample request. What do you see in Chrome's console when you log the `HttpEvent`? Mine says the type is `HttpResponse`. It should be listed as the very first thing before you expand it to get the details. It also says that it is `type: 4`

Comment: my sincere apologies Daniel. I think I looked that the print in a hurry and missed it. The code is working. I feel bad that I wasted your time :(. Please accept my apologies.